# Data frames number of rows from an imported csv file reaches max 40k

Tags: r, rstudio

Whenever I import a csv file into rstudio, my data frames reach a max number of observations of 40k, if of course, the data frame contains more than 40k. I have tried removing variables to make the file smaller but I still max out at 40k. I run rstudio on my laptop with 12 GB of Ram (11.9 GB usable). There has to be a reason for this but is there a way to remove this max or perhaps make it greater?

Comment: Which function are you using to read the data?

Comment: I've tried `read.csv` and `fread`.